# vlan with linux bridge ping not working

Tags: bridge, vlan, openstack

I want to configure the bridge `br-mgmt` with VLAN. I created the VLAN and bridge, then assigned IP addresses to the bridge, but `ping` is not working.

My netplan configuration looks like this:

server 1

```
root@server1:~# cat /etc/netplan/02-netcfg.yaml
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp5s0:
      dhcp4: no
  vlans:
    vlan.50:
      id: 50
      link: enp5s0
  bridges:
    br-mgmt:
      interfaces: [vlan.50]
      addresses: [ 192.168.50.194/24 ]
```

server 2

```
root@server2:~# cat /etc/netplan/02-netcfg.yaml
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp5s0:
      dhcp4: no
  vlans:
    vlan.50:
      id: 50
      link: enp5s0
  bridges:
    br-mgmt:
      interfaces: [vlan.50]
      addresses: [ 192.168.50.195/24 ]
```

ping test

```
root@server1:~# ping 192.168.50.195
PING 192.168.50.195 (192.168.50.195) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.50.194 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.50.194 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
```

Am I missing somehting?

---

- ubuntu: 22.02 server
- kernel verstion : 5.15.0-75-generic
- systemd-networkd daemon for netplan

Comment: how are "server 1" and "server 2" *physically* connected?

Comment: yes.  If  I assgin Ip to `enp5s0` directly. ping is works! is there any extra confiuration likes `kernel parameter` something?

Comment: I didn't ask IF they are connected, I asked HOW they are connected. Direct cable? through an unmanaged switch? through a managed switch? wifi? tin cans and string?

Comment: they are connected by  kvm `virtual bridge`     servers are running on kvm as a virtual machine.

Comment: oh, there was no mention of virtual machines in the question